# How to set GET param to current Request?

Tags: 8, http-request

I created a service and it works as well.

A piece of my code from "event_subscriber":

```
public function addRequestAddValue(GetResponseEvent $event) {
  $request = $event->getRequest();
  $request->query->add(['key' => '123']);
}
```

And than I try get this param on my Controller all Ok:

```
$key = \Drupal::request()->query->get('key');
dsm($key); // return 123
```

But if I try get URL I can see only:

```
$url = \Drupal::request()->getUri();
dsm($url); //return http://localhoct.dv/patn
```

What I need do to get URI with GET param?

Thanks

Comment: The method [`Request::getUri()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Request.php/function/Request%3A%3AgetUri/8.2.x) adds the query parameter to its output.